# How to close a different WinForm from another's WinForm's code?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I close a different WinForm (B) from a different WinForm's (A) code?

I already have it set up so WinForm (B) gets opened in WinForm (A)'s code:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make two changes to your code:

- Use `Show` instead of `ShowDialog` so that the first window can still handle events.
- Keep a reference to the form you opened.

Here's some example code:

```
Form2 form2;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form2.Close();
}
```

You will need to add some logic to make sure that you can't close a form before you have opened it, and that you don't try to close a form that you've already closed.

Comment: When I use Show(); my form2 freezes up.  I am also able to still handle methods in my first form when ShowDialog is used.  I'm not sure what's going on with that, but I'm sticking with it because that's whats working currently...

Answer (score 0):

Il you apply the "Show" method to a Winform, this one continues to listen to Windows messages, like WM_CLOSE. But if you use "ShowDialog", your winform becomes "deaf".

Just write form2.show(), and your winform will do whatever you want :-)